# What are the symptoms of a stack overflow in a C++ program?

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

I just ran into an issue where a stack overflow in a threaded c++ program on HPUX caused a SEGV_MAPERR when a local object tried to call a very simple procedure.  I was puzzled for a while, but luckily I talked to someone who recognized this as a stack size issue and we were able to fix the problem by increasing the stack size available to the threads.

How can I recognize when the stack overflows?  Do the symptoms differ on windows/linux/hpux?

Comment: That's funny... the stackoverflow tag would be appropriate, except nobody uses it for actual stack overflows.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering who was the joker who put up the stackoverflow tag. :-)

Comment: It's hard to search for actual stack overflow information on this site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I recognize when the stack overflows?

If you know the stack size, where the stack starts and the direction it grows in memory, you can simply check the address of the [stack pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_pointer#Structure) and see if it past the end of the stack. C++ does not allow direct access to the stack pointer. You could easily write a small function in assembly to perform this analysis and link it into you program.

Comment: Checking the stack pointer seems useful to tell whether the error in question is a stack overflow or a different type of memory corruption.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you're not on a platform thats going to stop your app and say "stack overflow" I suspect you'll see the same behavior that you would see from any kind of buffer overflow. The stack is just another preallocated chunk of memory for your program, and if you go outside those bounds... well good luck! Who knows what you'll stomp on!

You could write over the temperature readout from the CPU, it could be the email you're typing to Larry, it could be the bit saying that the kernel is locked, causing a fun deadlock condition! Who knows.

As for C++, there's nothing saying how the stack should be laid out in relation to other things in memory or that this thing even needs to be a stack!

Answer (score 1):

Exception code `0xC00000FD` on Windows.

Usually it's easier to diagnose when you realize your SEH stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit off topic, but the analagous issue in Ada (running out of stack space in tasks) is a rather common "uncommon" error. Many compilers will stop the task (but not the main task) with a PROGRAM_ERROR exception.

In a way, you almost have to be able to sniff out this one. It tends to start with something like, "I moved this big array inside my task, and suddenly it quit working".

Answer (score -1):

Output text to screen became mixed with lines of code from program under test. Also present were previous bash commands and other text of unidentified origin. Added to all that the program text became corrupted.